# How to filter those TCP packets on Wireshark/Ethereal?

Tags: wireshark

Packets that I want to see (just samples, there are thousands of them):

```
314 2.280146    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 TCP ah-esp-encap > 11188 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=121
316 2.290003    192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1 TCP 11188 > ah-esp-encap [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=122 Win=5840 Len=98
```

Packets that I want to be filtered out:

```
311 2.279182    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 TCP ah-esp-encap > 11188 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460
312 2.279404    192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1 TCP 11188 > ah-esp-encap [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
312 2.279404    192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1 TCP 11188 > ah-esp-encap [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
312 2.279404    192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1 TCP 11188 > ah-esp-encap [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460
```

How to write that filter?
I think the main difference between them is that I want only the PSH packets, and I want to exclude the SYN packets. I looked at the [reference](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html) but I don't understand it yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
tcp.flags.push == 1
```

Comment: And why did it work?